# Вывод результата JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Начал изучение JS. Столкнулся с проблемой, что результат который должен выводить JS не отображается. Что можно сделать с этой проблемой?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        window.onload=init;

    function init(){
        var button=document.getElementById("butt");
        button.onclick=buttonHandler;
    }
    function buttonHandler(){
        var feet = document.getElementById("feet");
        var f=feet.value;
        var weight= document.getElementById("weight");
        var w=weight.value;
        var result=document.getElementById("result");
        var r=w+f;
        result.innerHTML=r;
}

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Форма JS</h1>
    <form action="#" id="bmiCalculator">
        <label for="feet" for="inches">Height:</label>
        <input type="text" id="feet"> feet<br>

        <label for="pounds">Weight:</label>
        <input type="text" id="pounds">pounds <br><br>
        <input type="button" id="butt" value="Calculate!">
    </form>
    <p>Your BMI: <output id="result"></output></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя неверное указано значение в getElementById. Ты указал getElementById("weight"), а элемент у тебя называется pounds:`<input type="text" id="pounds">pounds <br>`
Нужно вот это:

```
var weight= document.getElementById("weight");
```

заменить на это:

```
var weight= document.getElementById("pounds");
```

И будет все работать.